# angularJs get old value from input

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm new in angularJs and I tried to get old value to could edit data in database.

```
$scope.editName=function(OldName, newName){
    $http.post("/api/data/edit/"+OldName+"/"+newName, {
    }).then(function(response){
        $scope.getData();
    },function(error){
    });
};
```

and in my html

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in data">
  <td ng-show="!show">{{data.name}}</td>
  <td ng-show="show">
      <input type="text" class="form-text" size="20" ng-model="data.name">
  </td>
  <td>
      <a ng-click="show = ! show" ng-show="!show" title="<?php print t("Edit"); ?>"><?php print t("Edit"); ?></a>
      <a ng-click="show = ! show;editName(???, data.name)" ng-show="show" title="<?php print t("Save"); ?>"><?php print t("Save"); ?></a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I don't know how to get old value and how could I do the update in my database. I'm just getting the new value

Comment: You change value in input then edit?

Comment: `$watch` can help you in that regard .

Answer (score 0):

Set the initial value as a new property on the data object when the page loads

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, data) {
    angular.forEach(data, function (dataEntry) {
        dataEntry.oldName = dataEntry.name;
    });
});
```

Then in HTML call `editName(data.oldName, data.name)` as such

```
<a ng-click="show = ! show;editName(data.oldName, data.name)" ng-show="show" title="<?php print t("Save"); ?>"><?php print t("Save"); ?></a>
```